# saveasTextFile("path") in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I used Scala in Spark, and I tried to save my file in HDFS file, but I got an error.

I have tried `rdd.saveAsTextFile("path"); sc.saveAsTextFile("pathe");
saveAsTextFile("path")`

```
scala> inputJPG.map(x=>x.split("")).map(array=>array(0)).sc.saveAsTextFile("/loudacre/iplist")
    <console>:28: error: value sc is not a member of Array[String]
                  inputJPG.map(x=>x.split("")).map(array=>array(0)).sc.saveAsTextFile("/loudacre/iplist")
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What is the structure of your file and what kind of data is in there? Are you simply trying to write a dataframe to hadoop? Have you read this page? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html

Comment: You should not include `.sc` here, just use `.saveAsTextFile(...)` on the RDD. However, it looks like you work with an `Array[String]` in which case you can't use RDD functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a new student and still learning Scala, so not familiar with RDD and Scala function.
Turn to my problem.I found that is because I have 
`val xx=data.collect()`before which is not RDD, so I can't do data.saveAsTextFile in Spark.
So I moved the `.collect()` function => `val xx=data` 
Then data.savaAsTextFile("path") works.